# Reusing SAPUI5 control

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an image and I need to use it at three places in a page. I can create three image objects and use them separately at the required places. However, I need to know if there is any way to reuse the single image object at three places. I tried to use prototype property of javascript but it is not working. I initially tried this but only footer gets the image.

```
var image = new sap.m.Image("id_image",{
        src:"images/myImage.png"
    });
return new sap.m.Page("id_page",{
        enableScrolling:false,
        customHeader:new sap.m.Bar("id_headerbar",{
            contentRight:image
        }),
        content: [

        ],
        footer:new sap.m.Bar("id_footerbar",{
            contentLeft:image
        }),
    });
```

I tried to use the prototype property :

```
   var image = new sap.m.Image();
   image.prototype.src = "./images/myImage.png";
```

But it says: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined.
Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you can simply declare `var image = new sap.m.Image(src: "./images/myImage.png");` and then reference the variable `image` at multiple places in your UI

Comment: @Qualiture It does not work. I tried this but the object declared at last is used and rest two are never used.

Comment: @Qualiture i edited the code so that you can understand what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: From my perspective this is neither possible nor recommendable. Think about the HTML that will be produced. You will always have HTML nodes for your image. So you can have the same picture three times but not the same picture (object) itself at three different positions. If you want to have the same picture three times you could create a Constructor function returning a (new) configurated image object.

Comment: Tim is absolutely right :) It seems I haven't read your requirement properly... please ignore my first comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use clone for that. Following example may help you

```
var itemDialog = new sap.ui.commons.Image({
        src : "images/sort_asc.png",
        tooltip : "Sort",
        press : function() {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
```

and then use clone property whereever required.As for example for using it in Table column

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        template : itemDialog.clone(),
        width : "30px"          
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I have a question -  Is there any kind of problem using this method as specified by Tim in the comments above

Comment: yes the clone doesnot mean that it is reference to the same object.It is just the copy of that image.So if you make change in the clone it is not going to change the original one or any other clone of that image.